# CS1929 C# 'RfcParameterClass' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'

Tags: c#, linq, saprfc

**CS1929 C# 'RfcParameterClass' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Cast(ParallelQuery)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery'**

Hello everyone, I am making a method which works with SAP RFC connector. The connection works fine and I am able to get data from SAP easily but problem is with using this data. The CS1929 error causses the query on the bottom of the code. I would like to set a lot of "MLFBCode" instances from those data. Can anyone help me please? I am using VS 16.7.3 and .NET Core 3.1. Thank you a lot!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using RFCCONNECTORLib;
using SmartLab_System.AppConfig;
using SmartLab_System.Models;
using RfcData = RFCCONNECTORLib.RfcParameterClass;
using RfcRow = RFCCONNECTORLib.RfcFields;

namespace SmartLab_System.Data
{
    public static class RFCMethodsForSLS
    {
        private static NWRfcSession Session = new NWRfcSession();
        //Info: https://rfcconnector.com/documentation/api/session/
        public static bool WasConnected { get; private set; } = true;
        public static Regex RegexPattern { get; private set; } = new Regex(Validation.MLFBLuke);

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls the "Connecting" method which returns wanted MLFB entries from SAP
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputString">String which will be searched</param>
        /// <param name="strLanguage">Set language "CS", "EN", "DE", ...</param>
        /// <param name="maxRows">Set maximum returned rows count</param>
        public static List<MLFBCode> GetMLFBData(string inputString, int maxRows = 100000, string strLanguage = "CS", string onlyIn4711 = "X")
        {
            string functionName = "/SIE/AD_ZPE_TL_MAT_INFO";
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> inputParameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            List<string> outPutParameters = new List<string>();

            inputParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("INPUT_STRING", inputString));
            inputParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LANG", strLanguage));
            inputParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ONLY_IN_4711", onlyIn4711));

            outPutParameters.Add("MLFB");               // mlfb
            outPutParameters.Add("MATNR");              // matnr (number)
            outPutParameters.Add("MAKTG");              // text  (description)
            outPutParameters.Add("DEL_STAT");           // vymaz na urovni master dat           - "X" means Deleted
            outPutParameters.Add("DEL_STAT_WERK");      // vymaz na urovni zavodu               - "X" means Deleted
            outPutParameters.Add("DEL_DISPO_99");       // docasny vymaz na urovni disponenta   - "X" means Deleted
            outPutParameters.Add("DEL_STAT_LV");        // docasny vymaz statusem               - "X" means Deleted
            outPutParameters.Add("EXISTS_IN_4711");     // material zalozen pro nas zavod       - "X" means was set for OEZ

            RfcData data = (RfcData)Connecting(functionName, inputParameters);
            List<MLFBCode> mLFBs = new List<MLFBCode>();
            List<RFCOutputData> rFCOutputData = new List<RFCOutputData>();

            mLFBs = (from RfcRow dataRow in data
                           select new MLFBCode()
                           {
                               MLFB = dataRow["MLFB"].ToString(),
                               Number = dataRow["MLFB"].ToString(),
                               Description = dataRow["MAKTG"].ToString(),
                               IdGroup = 1,
                               Active = true
                           }).ToList();
            
            return mLFBs;
        }
```

Editting question - For sure I add the Connecting(functionName, inputParameters) method code:

```
private static Object Connecting(string functionName, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> inputParameters)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(Validation.MLFB);
        Object data = new { };
        string[,] resultTableArray = new string[,] { };
        SetRFC();   //Set login data
        if (!Session.IsConnected)
        {
            Session.Connect();      //Connection to SAP
            if (Session.IsConnected)
            {
                FunctionCall fn = Session.ImportCall(functionName); //Set call
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in inputParameters) //Inserting input parametters of the SAP function
                {
                    fn.Importing[param.Key].value = param.Value;
                }

                Session.CallFunction(fn, true);                                     //Calling the function
                data = fn.Tables["RESULT_TABLE"];                               //Getting data from SAP
                
            }
            else WasConnected = false;
        }
        if (WasConnected)
            Session.Disconnect();
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: What type does `Connecting(functionName, inputParameters)` really return?

Comment: It returns "Object data = fn.Tables["RESULT_TABLE"];". The "Tables" is "RfcParameters IFunctionCall.Tables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe the library you're using is [RFCConnector](https://github.com/rfcconnector/example-csharp).

But it's worth mentioning that this

```
 from RFCRow row in data
```

"*precompiled*" to this C# code

```
data.Cast<RFCRow>();
```

And as you can see there is no a method called `Cast` which is defined in your `RfcParameterClass` class and there is no an extension method with the same name which accept `RFCParameterClass` type as the first parameter, so it won't compile. I guess you need to do the following:

```
from RfcRow row in data.Rows
```

**UPDATE**

To have the actual value of a row you need to call `value` on this, so your code will be like this:

```
(from RfcRow dataRow in data.Rows
 select new MLFBCode()
 {
     MLFB = dataRow["MLFB"].value.ToString(),
     Number = dataRow["MLFB"].value.ToString(),
     Description = dataRow["MAKTG"].value.ToString(),
     IdGroup = 1,
     Active = true
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: data.Rows works without error but the parameters of each new instance (MLFB, Description and Number) have the value: "RFCCONNECTORLib.RfcFieldClass".  As you wrote - I am using RFCConnector but the name of library is RFCCONNECTORLib as you can see on the top of my code. I am sorry about my expertise but I am still on the beginning with C#. Where is the problem now? In each parameter of MLFBCode should be some absolutely diferent strings. Thank you again!

Comment: I have found the problem. Final code is here: mLFBs = (from RfcRow dataRow in data.Rows
                           select new MLFBCode()
                           {
                               MLFB = dataRow["MLFB"].value.ToString(),
                               Number = dataRow["MATNR"].value.ToString(),
                               Description = dataRow["MAKTG"].value.ToString(),
                               IdGroup = 1,
                               Active = true
                           }).ToList();

Comment: @Mazounn Yes, I've just updated my answer with the code needed.

Comment: I dont know how to put the code now but the error was that before "ToString()" there should have been even "value". Thank you a lot! Have nice day a goodbye :-)